# add size atributes to an image with markdown using remark

Tags: image, next.js, markdown, size, width

I have a blog made with Nextjs s that uses markdown in posts using remark lib

The problem is in lighthouse audit asks for [size attributes](https://web.dev/uses-responsive-images) in images

is there any way to add width height attributes in html tags generated by remark?

I've already checked all possible questions on StackOverflow and none of them answer my request please don't suggest another topic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can be done in remark but I've done this in `ReactMarkdown`.

This blog explains it well: https://amirardalan.com/blog/use-next-image-with-react-markdown#add-custom-metastring-logic

This example from the blog parses the data from the image and adds it as a parameter to ReactMarkdown.

So you'd say something like `![some alt text {200x100}](/my/image.png)`

then you'd be able to read in the alt text and add it into the image element.

```js
export const imgCustom = (imageData) => {

  const size = imageData.alt?.match(/\{(\d+)x(\d+)\}/)  // Regex to look for sizing pattern  
  const width = size ? size[1] : "400"
  const height = size ? size[2] : "250"

  return (
      <Image
        src={image.properties.src}
        width={width}
        height={height}
      />
  )
},
```

```js
<ReactMarkdown components={{ img: imgCustom }}>{markdown}</ReactMarkdown>
```